# JMeter - When not to use Once Only controller

Tags: jmeter

[Once Only controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) component finish with a strange warning:

> Once Only controller under anything other than the Thread Group or a Loop Controller is not currently defined. Odd things may happen.

I check and it works in setup/tearDown Thread Group and other Controllers and it works fine and in other components (as Pre/Post processor/Config...) it can't be added.

What is the use case for this disturbing warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnceOnlyController reacts to its parent loop and runs only if it's the first iteration.
It expects its parent to be a LoopController or a Thread Group which contains a Loop Controller but it now handles also other elements.

There used to be a bug which has been fixed:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39509

I suspect the comment is now outdated, but if you can test more and possibly provide some Test plan testing all combinations it would help the project strengthen this part.

Note removed by:

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1813138